# Sencha Touch: Ability to have a dot next to unread items in a list

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm just wondering if there's a way to have a dot next to unread items in a list and then to keep track of which items were read and which weren't? (Like the Mail app on iOS)

I know I could do this manually but I'm wondering if this is already catered for in the framework. My extensive hunting has turned up nothing so I thought I'd ask here before looking to write something myself.

Comment: Are you talking about Ext.dataview.List? How can you *read* a list item? I think you need to elaborate on your problem. Can you provide some code, preferably a working [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/)?

Comment: Ideally your data store for list should have persisted information about whether that was opened or not so that when you fetch that data again or load the app again, you would always get `isRead` kind of flag and on its basis you should render your template.

Comment: Just what @ThinkFloyd said, put it in localStorage, but to answer your question (sort of), I don't think there's a way for Sencha Touch to do this out the box.

Comment: @ThinkFloyd basically has what I was thinking of. I only want to keep the read status locally per app instance and not persist it to the server. I'd use the unique key of the list item to store whether it's been read or not. My question more revolved around whether there is an existing module that you can plugin that does the little blue dot next to a list item similar to Mail on iOS that marks an unread item. I guess it's not hard to do manually though but it seems like it'd be a common thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this can be done manually, there doesn't seem to exist a plugin or capability to do it as part of the list module.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dot as a css class by default to the list item. in the itemtap event remove the class.

Comment: That's correct, but it's not the answer to the question. I was searching for a module or plugin that already does this.

Comment: In hindsight I agree. I just couldn't mark your answer as THE answer because it didn't answer the question. I'm happy to mark it as THE answer if you update it to include the essence of my answer.